# How to know if the phone on a call in Unity?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a game in Unity, and i want to detect if the 
(iPhone) device is During a phone call or not, actually the game crashes during the phone call.

I think the problem is while I am recording the game session, I am also record the game sounds and effects :

```
private void StartMicrophone () { // Create a microphone clip 
    microphoneSource.clip = Microphone.Start(null, true, 60, 48000); 
    microphoneSource.loop = true; 

    while (!(Microphone.GetPosition(null) > 0)) { } 

    microphoneSource.Play(); 
}
```

Comment: Call is not main problem , When unity app goes background it calles OnApplication Pause and your logic must go there https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html more look here

Comment: Please show us your code which you think might be responsible for the crash

Comment: i think the problem is while i am recording the game session, i am also record the game sounds and effects : 
private void StartMicrophone () {
            // Create a microphone clip
            microphoneSource.clip = Microphone.Start(null, true, 60, 48000);
            microphoneSource.loop = true;
            while (!(Microphone.GetPosition(null) > 0))
            {
            }
            microphoneSource.Play();
        }

Comment: it is maybe i can't access the microphone since it is controller by the phone during the phone call, but how to detect this in order to prevent recording during the call ?

Answer (score 1):

When the phone receives a call, your app starts to run in background.

The problem is that unity doesn't run in background for IOS or Android, [check](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-runInBackground.html).

To fix this problem I would recommend to use another editor, you can try to look for Xamarin, and embed the unity viewer into your app and try to setup a background functionality, but it won't be possible with unity.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the game should just pause when it is no longer the currently active application, the crash might be caused by microphone permission issues, so if you just want to prevent the crash, giving back the microphone access in OnApplicationPause might be enough